# Call JavaScript function in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

How can i call JavaScript method in Xamarin?. I found library to this(https://github.com/chkn/HybridKit), but unfortunately, this tool can call C# function in JavaScript. For Xamarin.Forms i found one solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could want to Call html JavaScript function in C#, if yes, you can take a look:

There are index.html,added in PCL,setting **Build Action** as EmbeeddedResource,  there is one function, named printMultiplicationTable

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<div id='multiplicationtable'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printMultiplicationTable(num, stop)
{
var number = parseInt(num);
var stopNumber = parseInt(stop);

$('#multiplicationtable').empty();
for (var index = 1; index <= stopNumber; index++) {
    $('#multiplicationtable').append(number + ' x ' + index + " = " + number * index + '<br/>');
}
}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, you want to call this JavaScript function in C#,

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label
        FontSize="Medium"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Text="Multiplication Table" />
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Number: " VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Entry
            x:Name="numberEntry"
            Text="5"
            WidthRequest="40" />
        <Label Text="Stop:" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Entry
            x:Name="stopEntry"
            Text="10"
            WidthRequest="40" />
    </StackLayout>
    <Button
        x:Name="callJavaScriptButton"
        Clicked="OnCallJavaScriptButtonClicked"
        Text="Call JavaScript" />
    <WebView
        x:Name="webView"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>

 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webView.Source = LoadHTMLFileFromResource();
    }
    HtmlWebViewSource LoadHTMLFileFromResource()
    {
        var source = new HtmlWebViewSource();

        // Load the HTML file embedded as a resource in the PCL
        var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("CallJavaScript.index.html");
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            source.Html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return source;
    }

    private void OnCallJavaScriptButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numberEntry.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stopEntry.Text))
        {
            return;
        }

        int number = int.Parse(numberEntry.Text);
        int end = int.Parse(stopEntry.Text);

        webView.Eval(string.Format("printMultiplicationTable({0}, {1})", number, end));
    }
```

This is my sample, you can get it from github:

https://github.com/CherryBu/CallJavaScript

**Update:**

[image]

**Update again:**

If you want to call html JavaScript function from C#, you can configure webview in MainActivity.cs:

```
  WebSettings settings = webview1.Settings;
        settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        // load the javascript interface method to call the foreground method
        //webview1.AddJavascriptInterface(new MyJSInterface(this), "CSharp");
        webview1.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());        
        webview1.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/login.html");
```

Please add html file in Assets folder, and set BuildAction as AndroidAsset.

Then C# calls a method in JS and gets the callback value

```
class EvaluateBack : Java.Lang.Object, IValueCallback
{

    public void OnReceiveValue(Object value)
    {

        Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context,value.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();// you will get the value "100"
    }


}

webview1.EvaluateJavascript("javascript: check();", new EvaluateBack());
```

This is sample at github you can take a look:

https://github.com/CherryBu/CallJavaFunction

Comment: Thanks for your example, but when i try to run your project, i ve got something like this: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: printMultiplicationTable is not defined", source:  (1)03-02 09:38:14.234 I/chromium(13561):

Comment: And when i try to run on real device i've got Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/ (13)

Comment: @Kamerel Do you try to download my sample to test? Because I don't have any issue when running my project, you can see gif. so please try to download my sample from github to test:https://github.com/CherryBu/CallJavaScript/tree/master/CallJavaScript/CallJavaScript

Comment: Yes, I am using your sample

Comment: @Kamerel Before I did the test on the simulator, it works fine. If you want to test on real device, please confirm the **decive connect internet firstly**, then you can see it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for this example, but i need solution for Xamarin.Android, not for Xamarin Forms.

Comment: @Kamerel  If you want to solution in Xamarin.Android, please take a look my update, provide one sample for op.

Comment: Is still the sample available? I have tried with your solution but when I evaluate any Javascript function nothing is happening