# Why doesn't the blur() method work in webview?

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

There is a page which has some input field. When I manually fill one field and press TAB, or just click somewhere on the page, the webpage automatically fill the other fields with some value.
I am writing an android app with xamarin.forms and I use webview for reach the page.
The input field what I want to fill in programmatically has **blur()** and **submit()** events as I saw.
My problem is, when my program successfully fills in that field and I call the blur() or submit() methods in javascript nothing happens only just that field has a value and the webpage not fills the other fields.

```
webview.Eval("var x = document.getElementById('fieldID');");
webview.Eval($"x.value='{something}';");
webview.Eval("x.sumbit();");
webview.Eval("x.focus();");
webview.Eval("x.blur();");
```

I tried a combination of these but it didn't work at all.
Does anyone have any idea what to do?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: According to your description, you want to call javascript method, there is `blur()` method in JavaScript? For example, there is one method check() in Javascript, I use `webview1.EvaluateJavascript("javascript: check();", new EvaluateBack());`, take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60447855/call-javascript-function-in-xamarin

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Thanks for the answer. Finally I solved it differently.